# How to parse JSON object without tag

Tags: java, android, json

How to parse a json array without object tags?
How can I get files?

```
{
    "id": "476",
    //IDобращения"status": "2",
    //Статус: 0=>'Нарассмотрении',
    1=>'Вработе',
    2=>'Выполнено',
    3=>'Отклонено'"latitude": "56.007831",
    //геокоординаты,
    заданныеприподачеобращения"longitude": "35.970359",
    "message": "dfghdfgh",
    //текстобращения"published_at": "2014-01-30 18:13:29",
    //датаподачиобращения"comments": [
        {
            "id": 133,
            "message": "aaa",
            //тексткомментария(админ/пользователь)"isadmin": "0",
            //ответданадминистратором(isadmin=1)"curr_status": "1"//статусобращениянамоментответа
        },
        {
            "id": 134,
            "message": "112",
            "isadmin": "1",
            "curr_status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 136,
            "message": "",
            "isadmin": "1",
            "curr_status": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": 137,
            "message": "123",
            "isadmin": "1",
            "curr_status": "2"
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        “”,
        ””……””//image(base64encoded)
    ]
}
```

```
  JSONObject result = new JSONObject(s);
            id = result.getInt("id");
            status = result.getInt("status");
            latitude = result.getDouble("latitude");
            longitude = result.getDouble("longitude");
            message = result.getString("message");
            dateOfPublish = result.getString("published_at");
            JSONArray jsonArray = result.getJSONArray("files");

            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                //Here i want to get files
            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: You could add `{` and `}`

Comment: no, i know ho to parse json, i don't know how to parse json without object tag?

Comment: @SKaks, look my edited question

Comment: The files is a property of the top-level object, files is an array. What is the problem?

Comment: @peter.petrov, how can i get it from code?

Comment: I see. Post your code, I am pretty sure somebody will figure it out.

Comment: @peter.petrov, i have added my code, look it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling this method. That should do it.

[JSONArray.get](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#get%28int%29)

Comment: and then convert to String?

Comment: Yes, sure, or to whatever you have in your JSON file. If it's string you have - cast it to string, yes. Just stop there in a debugger (or print this Object), and you'll see what Object you get back.

Comment: i am going to try it now

Comment: Yes, it helped me. And a don't know why i got a lot of minuses(

Comment: That was obvious :) You just overlooked it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you should try this (I didn't test it):

```
    for(int n = 0; n < JSONArray.length(); n++)
    {
       JSONObject object = JSONArray.getJSONObject(n);
       String file = object.get("");
       // do some stuff....
    }
```